# How to enable mutual SSL verification mode in Redhat-SSO image for OpenShift

Tags: openshift, redhat-sso

I am using the template sso72-x509-postgresql-persistent, which is based on Redhat-SSO and Keycloak, to create an application in OpenShift.

I am going to enable its mutual SSL mode, so that a user has to only provide his certificate instead of user name and password in his request. The document (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_single_sign-on/7.2/html-single/server_administration_guide/index#x509) told me to edit the standalone.xml file to add configuration sections. It worked fine.

But the template image sso72-x509-postgresql-persistent had problem with this procedure, because after it was deployed on the OpenShift, any changes on the files within the docker have been lost after restart of the docker.

Is there anyway to enable the mutual SSL mode through another level matter like commandline or API instead of editting a configuration file, except making my own docker image?

Answer (score 1):

**Ok, I'm including this anyway. I wasn't able to get this working due to permissions issues (the mounted files didn't persist the same permissions as before, so the container continued to fail. But a lot of work went into this answer, so hopefully it points you in the right direction!**

---

You can add a Persistent Volume (PV) to ensure your configuration changes survive a restart. You can add a PV to your deployment via:

**DON'T DO THIS**

```
oc set volume deploymentconfig sso --add -t pvc --name=sso-config --mount-path=/opt/eap/standalone/configuration --claim-mode=ReadWriteOnce --claim-size=1Gi
```

This will bring up your RH-SSO image with a blank `configuration` directory, causing the pod to get stuck in `Back-off restarting failed container`. What you should do instead is:

1. Backup the existing configuration files

   ```
   oc rsync <rhsso_pod_name>:/opt/eap/standalone/configuration ~/
   ```
2. Create a temporary, `busybox` deployment that can act as an intermediary for uploading the configuration files. *Wait for deployment to complete*

   ```
   oc run busybox --image=busybox --wait --command -- /bin/sh -c "while true; do sleep 10; done"
   ```
3. Mount a new PV to the `busybox` deployment. *Wait for deployment to complete*

   ```
   oc set volume deploymentconfig busybox --add -t pvc --name=sso-volume --claim-name=sso-config --mount-path=/configuration --claim-mode=ReadWriteOnce --claim-size=1Gi
   ```
4. **Edit your configuration files now**
5. Upload the configuration files to your new PV via the `busybox` pod

   ```
   oc rsync ~/configuration/ <busybox_pod_name>:/configuration/
   ```
6. Destroy the `busybox` deployment

   ```
   oc delete all -l run=busybox --force --grace-period=0
   ```
7. **Finally**, you attach your already created and ready-to-go persistent configuration to the RH SSO deployment

   ```
   oc set volume deploymentconfig sso --add -t pvc --name=sso-volume --claim-name=sso-config --mount-path=/opt/eap/standalone/configuration
   ```

Once your new deployment is...still failing because of permission issues :/